# Changing a fluid site to two fixed breakpoints in Susy 2

Tags: responsive-design, susy-compass, susy-sass

I created a fluid site for a client using Susy 2/breakpoint However they want to change the site to show the mobile layout less than 320px and then the desktop zoomed out ( like loading a fixed width site) on any device above 321px.

Is there a way to change Susy setting so I don't have to rewrite it fixed width and should I be aware of anything in the viewport meta tags?

Comment: can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: Sorry this is in test: [Test site](http://sse.gunkdesign.co.uk)


Basically, the client has a view at 320px that they want to keep for mobile. Then on sizes above that show the desktop view.

I have the H5BP meta tag in there and that throws up some issues, especially with viewport resizing.

I did some tests and if I change all the percentage values to px then I can force the desktop version. But then I get some orientation issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your meta tag from

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 to
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
```

this will set the  mobile layout(only portrait mode) at 320px and for the rest of the resolutions it will show desktop version of the site.

Comment: I guess for this to work I also need to change my desktop layout to be in fixed pixel widths and not percentages too, to force the viewport sizing?

Comment: Thanks that worked, sorry I have another question. Is there a way to get the desktop view to scale to the device width i.e. if the viewport is greater than 320px show desktop but scale it to the available viewport?